# Laravel Forge Add Wildcard Subdomain to Existing

Tags: laravel, nginx, laravel-forge

How do I add Wildcard Subdomains to a site I already created? When you first create one I know you can check a box but how do you do so after the fact? Do I have to edit the NGINX Config file?

I tired placing this in the `server{}` section: `server_name ~^(.*)\.mydomain\.com$ ;` but it didnt work. I have always used .htaccess so I am not too familiar with NGINX

NGINX Config File I tried

```
 server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name mydomain.com;
    server_name ~^(.*)\.mydomain\.com$

    root /home/forge/mydomain.com/public;

    # FORGE SSL (DO NOT REMOVE!)
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/mydomain.com/321141/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/mydomain.com/321141/server.key;

    MORE BELOW
```

if I go to `mydomain.com` I get my site, but if I go to app.mydomain.com I get `server IP address could not be found.`. On my local environment I have sub domain routing so when I go to that subdomain with Valet it works.

Comment: I believe you have to add an `A` record with the value as `*` in your DNS configuration.

Comment: @user2094178 I have a A record setup but nothing still

Answer (score 5):

Okay for it to work you need to do 2 things:

First, set up your A record on your DNS so its host is `*` and it points to your server IP

Then, in your NGINX config file for the site you just need to change:

`server_name mydomain.com;`

to

`server_name .mydomain.com;`

Notice the `.` before the domain name. It should then work (might take a little time for the DNS to recognize it, but worked).