# Laravel subdomain endpoint keeps redirecting with 301 error

Tags: laravel, routes, subdomain

I have a working Laravel app and have introduced a subdomain (api.mysite.com) to handle programmatic access by my users. I've set up a route group at the top of my routes file:

```
Route::group(['domain' => 'api.' . config('app.domain'), 'middleware' => 'api'], function () {
    Route::get('/some-endpoint','APIController@someHandler');
});
```

This arrangement works locally.

I added an A record to my DNS records pointing the `api` subdomain at my site's IP:

```
A Record    api    XX.XXX.XXX.XXX    Automatic
```

The problem is that when I try to access `api.mysite.com/some-endpoint` when deployed to production the site responds with a 301 and tries to redirect me to `mysite.com/some-endpoint` which doesn't have a route in my routes file and thus replies with a 404.

Comment: From what I read this post has nothing to do with Laravel routes, but with your server configuration. Maybe you should post your vhost configuration file and which webserver you use. It is likely that you don't have a vhost for the api subdomain.

Comment: Do I need a 'server' entry for the subdomain in my nginx config?

Comment: That's not my core area of expertise, but it might be enough to specify it in the server name like `server_name  domain.tld  api.domain.tld`. It should then handle both.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. It was my nginx config. I'll add an answer to this question for completeness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem existed in my nginx config file. In the `server` section I needed to change the line

```
server_name mysite.com;
```

to

```
server_name .mysite.com;
```

See [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49313076/laravel-forge-add-wildcard-subdomain-to-existing). Be aware, however, that the wildcard server name lookups resulting from names like `.mysite.com` are slower than those resulting from explicitly defined names like `mysite.com www.mysite.com api.mysite.com`.

See also the [nginx documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html):

> A special wildcard name in the form “.example.org” can be used to match both the exact name “example.org” and the wildcard name “*.example.org”.

Comment: Please note that it is discouraged to use the wildcard form `.mysite.com`. You should put all domains there explicitly, i.e. `server_name mysite.com api.mysite.com` (see http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html#optimization)